# React Js Can not delete record from API

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I am  failing to delete the clients from the API, i expected to click on `Onclick` button and the data should be deleted from the database:

**Using the onclick button, the data should be deleted**:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import ReactToPrint from 'react-to-print'
import { Table, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'

const Hello = () => {
  alert('Name, Description, Start Date, End Date, Validity, Status')
}

class clientview extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      clients: []
    }
    this.deleteTask = this.deleteTask.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    const url = 'http://localhost:3001/clients/sel_all'

    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        result => {
          console.log(result)
          this.setState({
            clients: result.data
          })
        },
        error => {
          this.setState({ error })
        }
      )
  }
  deleteTask (id, url = 'http://localhost:3001/clients/delete') {
    return fetch(url + '/' + id, { method: 'DELETE' }).then(response =>
      response.json()
    )
  }

  render () {
    const { error, clients, props } = this.state

    if (error) {
      return <div> Error:{error.message}</div>
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>All Clients</h2>
          <Table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Client Name</th>
                <th>Client Address</th>
                <th>Comment</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
              {clients.map(client => (
                <tr key={client.id}>
                  <td>{client.id}</td>
                  <td>{client.name}</td>
                  <td>{client.address}</td>
                  <td>{client.comment}</td>
                  <td>
                    <button onClick={Hello}>View Contract</button>
                    <button>
                      <ReactToPrint
                        trigger={() => <button>print</button>}
                        content={() => this.componentRef}
                      />
                    </button>
                    <button
                      onClick={() => {
                        props.editRow(client)
                      }}
                      className='button'
                    >
                      Edit
                    </button>
                  </td>
                  <button
                    onClick={() => {
                      this.deleteTask.bind(this)
                    }}
                  >
                    Dele
                  </button>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
}
export default clientview
```

Comment: Is there an error ? do you have any logs from the response ? or log from the API side ?

Comment: try `this.deleteTask(client.id)` instead of `this.deleteTask.bind(this)`!

Comment: The way you created onClick handler will never invoke.

Comment: @RafaelHovsepyan there is nothing wrong with his declaration

Comment: @MaximeGirou you should go like this `onClick={this.deleteTask.bind(this, client.id)}` or `onClick={() => {this.deleteTask(client.id)}}`. In this code the handler is actually outer anonymous arrow function, and it just creates deleteTask function binded to component context. It will not call deleteTask method.

Comment: Maxime Girou, unfortunately, there is No response from the server side,

Comment: @AbdulazizIsmail because there is no request from client side:)

Comment: Yeah,  @RafaelHovsepyan is completely right. `bind` returns a new function with bounded context to it. But according the code it is never called.

Comment: @ MAximeGirou & Rafael: Trying to delete client whose id is 10, this is the log: DELETE /clients/delete/10 404 0.328 ms - 159

Comment: this is the log error: OPTIONS /clients/delete/5 204 1.996 ms - 0
DELETE /clients/delete/5 404 3.363 ms - 158

Comment: @RafaelHovsepyan my bad, the is nothing wrong with the declaration, but i didn't see that you talked about the call, there are somme issues there

Comment: @AbdulazizIsmail you have to check server side,

Comment: here is my server side: router.delete('/client', function(req, res){
  let client_id = req.body.client_id;
  if (!client_id){
    return res.status(400).send({error:true, message: "please provide client id"});
  }
    dbConn.query("DELETE FROM clients WHERE id=?",[client_id], function(error, results, fields){
      if (error) throw error;
        return res.send({error:false, data:results, message:"client has been updated successfully."});
        res.end("Record has been deleted");


    });
});

Comment: Solved, the problem is actually with the server.

Comment: Thank you @Rafael and Maxime.